# Display more options in list of store categories

Tags: php, foreach

How would I display only 6 categories on an archive listing page then a button to show more if there is more than 6 selected?

```
<?php
$terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'store_categories');
if ($terms && !is_wp_error($terms)):
    $store = array();
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $store[] = $term->name;
    }
    $store_category = join(" | ", $store);
?>
      <h3 id="storeCat">
            <?php
    $url = site_url();
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $linklist .= "<a href='" . $url . "/store_categories/" . $term->slug . "' target='_blank'>" . $term->name . "</a>" . "&nbsp; ";
    }
        echo $linklist;
?>
      </h3>
        <?php
endif;
?>
```

Comment: output the first 6 in one `<div>`, then the rest in another hidden `<div>` with some javascript on a button to make it show?

Comment: I'll rephrase my question. How would I only print 6 from this loop then a button to show the rest on the next row?